# Construct bash array with only string format

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, bash-array

Is there a way to pass a string value as env variable and have bash recognize it as an array? In other words, is there some special string format that tells bash that the string is an array? Or is otherwise array-like?

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

my_array="$this_is_an_env_var"
```

Comment: Related: [How to pass array to bash shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278544/170373), and probably others

Answer (score 3):

```
:> export ar=(foo bar baz) # create and "export" array
:> bash -c 'echo ${ar[1]}' # array is not visible in a regular child process

:> declare -p ar           # get a string which correctly creates the array
declare -a ar=([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="baz")
:> my_array="$(declare -p ar)" bash -c 'eval "$my_array";echo ${ar[1]}'
bar
```

The `eval` turns the string variable into an array variable. `eval` should only be used with trusted data sources, though.

Comment: @ilkkachu That should be enough.